# Bibliography and Citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

My question is concerning the actual citation style and how to represent it using `\printbibliography`.

In my text I want to cite as:

> *(Author X & Author Y Year)*

But in my bibliography I want it to be displayed as:

> Last Name Author X, First Name Author X (only Inital X.), Last Name Author Y, First Name Author Y (only Inital Y.) ........

---

I have tried a couple of things but without any success, like:

---

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{wombat2016,
    author   = {Walther Wombat and Klaus Koala},
    title    = {The true meaning of 42},
    journal  = {Journal of modern skepticism},
    date     = {2016},
    keywords = {trusted},
}
@book{lion2010,
    author       = {Laura Lion and  Gabrielle Giraffe and Carl Capybara},
    title        = {The dangers of asking the wrong question},
    publisher    = {publishing house},
    date         = {2010},
    keywords     = {trusted},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,citetracker=true,mincitenames=2,giveninits=true,maxbibnames=99,dashed=false,isbn=false,url=false,urldate=comp,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

All we know is limited, apart from knowing the answer we all know. Or do we? Wombat and Koala have discovered some interesting things~\parencite{wombat2016}.

Some people are too nosy. What can happen to them is described by Laura Lion~\cite[9]{lion2010}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, what style are you using? You can try `maxcitenames=2`.

Comment: \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,citetracker=true,maxcitenames=2,giveninits=false,maxbibnames=99,dashed=false,isbn=false,url=false,urldate=comp,natbib=true]{biblatex}

Comment: I added a minimal working example (based on https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber) with your original line (slightly modified, solves one issue already).

Comment: thank you @Johannes_B but thats not what i want  i want it to be:

something cite ( Smith & Penny 2018) and then down in the bibliography it should be 

Smith, T., Penny, T. something something 2018

Answer (score 3):

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

Changes the name order in the bibliography to 'Last, First'. Together with `giveninits=true` you get 'Last, F.'.

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

Gives '&' in citations and ', ' in the bibliography.

If you want small caps for last names, use

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, mincitenames=2, giveninits=true, maxbibnames=99, dashed=false, uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\begin{document}
\cite[123]{sigfridsson}

\cite[9]{companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: tried it but for some reason i get & in citation and & in the bibliography if its more than 2 authors the last ',' is always an '&'

Comment: @Peter Do you get an error about `\DeclareDelimFormat` not being recognised? It certainly works for me? Can you show me an exact MWE of what you tried to do?

Comment: i dont get an error, i dont know whats going wrong also when i cite it does the following (lastname author X & firstname initial Author Y, Year) i really dont know whats going wrong

Comment: Ok it works for the citation now, but still last author in the bibliography is always noted as " & Author"

Comment: @Peter Can you get my example to work? Just copy it over to your PC and run it, no changes are required. Does it give the same output as in the picture?

Comment: doesnt work it just gives a plain page that says in bold sigrudsson

Comment: @Peter Note that your original input of `author = {\textsc{X}, X. and \textsc{Y}{,} Y.},` is just wrong and can cause all sorts of weird output.

Comment: @Peter Ah, I remember you use BibTeX. Add `backend=bibtex` to my MWE and try again.

Comment: it works fine for me and does exactly what i want, just now this last & in the bibliography is hella annoying atm

Comment: @Peter As you can see from the picture, in my MWE the `&` is not there. Do you get the '&' with my code (and `backend=bibtex`)? What code do you use?

Comment: moewe i did what you said, and still: it works for two authors Author X & author Y for citation, but down in the bibliography it does the same, last author in each case is noted as & author....

Comment: added the output above, marked the "error" in red

Comment: @Peter What version of `biblatex` are you using?

Comment: i am using biblatex 3.7

Comment: @Peter That version is outdated. The current version is 3.10 Does My solution requires at least `biblatex` 3.8. `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}` work for you?

Comment: that works! and i found out how to solve my & citation problem thank you very much for your help !